# Farsightedness and the eye

Tags: vision

When a farsighted person looks at a distant object and sees it clearly, what is the state of their eye lens? Is it relaxed?

Rationale:

It is something we read about in class that is confusing.I know a person with 20/20 vision would have a relaxed lens when looking at a distant object. I think a farsighted person would have a relaxed lens when looking at far objects since they can see distant objects, but since they have trouble seeing close objects the lens would not be relaxed when looking at close objects. Those that are nearsighted would have a relaxed lens when looking at close objects, but not when looking at distant objects. So, a relaxed lens just means the eye does not need to strain when looking at something?

Comment: Is this a homework question? Please show us what have you researched so far regarding this. Maybe something from optics chapter?

Comment: related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/30504/what-is-the-difference-between-myopia-and-hyperopia?rq=1 - does that answer your question?